# Instantiating class in TypeScript giving "Argument of type is not assignable to a parameter of type"

Tags: typescript, handlebars.js

Below is my class -

```
export interface RaiseIncidentWidgetItem {

    Link: string;
    ImagePath: string;
}

export interface RaiseIncidentWidgetConfig {

    View?: string;
    SiteUrl : string;
    ListTitle : string;
}

export class RaiseIncidentWidget implements IWidget {

    constructor(public config: RaiseIncidentWidgetConfig) {

    }
}
```

I am using below code to instantiate my class object -

```
const config: RaiseIncidentWidgetConfig[] = new Array();

config.push({

        View : '',
        SiteUrl : '',
        ListTitle : '',

    });

const obj = new RaiseIncidentWidget(**config**);
```

When I instantiate the class, It is giving me error that

> "Argument of type 'RaiseIncidentWidgetConfig[]' is not assignable to a
>   parameter of type 'RaiseIncidentWidgetConfig'."

Comment: The error message is very clear. Just read it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Constructor of `RaiseIncidentWidget` accepts instance of `RaiseIncidentWidgetConfig` but you're passing an array of `RaiseIncidentWidgetConfig`

Change the constructor or the data you're passing there.